# Combining OSGi with Java SPI

Tags: java, design-patterns, osgi

I have a project that I am in the process of making OSGi compatible. The code relies on Java SPI for adding implementations (META-INF/services). I don't want to use SPI in OSGi environments (e.g. by using SPI Fly), I'd rather use the OSGi way. However, I want to keep SPI support for non-OSGi environments. My approach has been the following:

The factories look something like this (using BND annotations):

```
@Component
class MyFactory implements MyFactoryService {

    public MyFactory() {
         ...
    }

    //This method is reserved for non-OSGi use (uses SPI to find implementations)
    public static MyFactory newInstance() {
        MyFactory ret = new MyFactory();
        Iterator<MyDiscoverable> i = ServiceLoader.load(MyDiscoverable.class).iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            ret.addFactory(i.next());
        }
    }

    @Reference
    public void addFactory(MyDiscoverable f) {
        ...
    }

}
```

In an OSGi context, MyFactory is in an OSGi private package and must be retrieved through the service registry using the MyFactoryService interface. MyFactory is then populated by the OSGi framework using the @Reference annotation (or rather the declarative service generated from it).

If the implementations of MyDiscoverable require other factories similar to MyFactory, I put something like this in MyFactory.newInstance():

```
 public static MyFactory newInstance() {
        MyFactory ret = new MyFactory();
        MyOtherFactory other = MyOtherFactory.newInstance();
        Iterator<MyDiscoverable> i = ServiceLoader.load(MyDiscoverable.class).iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            MyDiscoverable x = i.next();
            //This method is also annotated with @Reference in the implementation, to support OSGi use
            x.setReference(other);
            ret.addFactory(x);
        }
}
```

This works alright in both OSGi and SPI context. One issue I have with this is that the factory must know which other factories each implementation might need (and supply them). This is because I haven't found a way to let the implementation create their own instances of the factories without making it incompatible with OSGi. This limitation is manageable for the most part, but it isn't acceptable as a general solution.

Is there a better way? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to explicitly provide MyDiscoverable with the information that it was created through newInstance, e,g. x.populateWithSPI(). This way, setReference could be called by the implementation itself with e.g. MyOtherFactory.newInstance()

Answer (score 0):

OSGI is uses an IOC container and like all IOC containers (Guice, Spring, etc..), the IOC container must be responsible for the instantiation of a class.

SPI enables discovery of implementations at runtime and SPI instantiates those implementations as part of the discovery.

You can't use the same class for SPI and OSGI (or any other IOC container) without a hack because they have different ways of instantiating a class. I recommend keeping the two approaches separate.

You could create a wrapper class around `MyFactoryService` that is used by SPI. The class could be called `MyFactoryServiceProvider` and it could return a class reference for `MyFactoryService` for you to instantiate and then pass references of `MyDiscoverable` to it.